# Rank of matrices and their product

Tags: matrices

Let $\operatorname{rank}(A_{3 \times 3})=\operatorname{rank}(B_{3 \times 3})=2$. I need to figure out whether $AB=0$ is possible. On the one hand, I know that $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \min(\operatorname{rank}\ A, \operatorname{rank}\ B)$, so there is a possibility that $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=0$ (and thus $AB=0$). On the other hand, I have a hard time finding an appropriate example of matrices for which it holds. Maybe I'm missing something very trivial.

Comment: Sylvester rank inequality

Comment: @sas - Thanks. Didn't know about this theorem.

Comment: @sas: Why don't you put that comment as an answer?

Comment: @voldemort: I didn't think about it as a proper answer. Well, OK, I'll add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$AB$ cannot be the zero matrix. proof by contradiction. if $AB$ is the zero matrix, then every column of $B$ is in the null space of $A.$ that $rank(B) = 2$ shows that the null space of $A$ has dimension $2.$ then $rank(A) + dim(ker(A)) = 2 + 2 = 4$ but the nullity theorem implies $rank(A) + dim(ker(A)) = 3$ and that is a contradiction we sought.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find an example. Consider the endomorphisms $f$ and $g$ of $ K^3$ (K is the base field) associated with A and B respectively. AB=0 means that $f\circ g=0$, or $\mathrm{im}\: g \subset \ker f $. As $\dim\:(\mathrm{im}\:  g)=2 ,$ this implies $\dim\:\ker f \geq 2$, which contradicts the rank theorem.

Comment: The thing is that we haven't learned about endomorphisms nor about the Sylvester rank inequality, so I thought there exists a simpler proof for why $AB \neq 0$. But thanks!

Comment: You misunderstood my answer. I meant the equivalent of the  rank-nullity theorem for linear maps. The Sylvester rank inequality is of a more technical nature.

Answer (score 0):

Sylvester rank inequality could help you.
For two square matrices of order $n$ $\operatorname{rank} A + \operatorname{rank}B \leq \operatorname{rank} AB + n$

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298836/sylvester-rank-inequality) is a good further explanation.