# How to show that $Rank(AB)\geq Rank(A)+Rank(B)-n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_{m \times n}$ and $B\in M_{n \times k}$. Prove that

$$Rank(AB)\geq Rank(A)+Rank(B)-n.$$

I have tried to use $Im(AB) \subseteq Im(B)$ but that lead me to nowhere, how should I approach this prove?

Comment: I've edited your title.  Please don't put all math in a title, it prevents users from right clicking and opening your question in a new page, which is a common way of browsing this site.

Comment: That's Sylvester Inequality, you can google for it first.

Comment: @Jim I will do it from now on

Comment: @gbox use null space ...

Comment: @Vim to be fair, you can't google for it if you don't know the name.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/438762/191404) for a simple proof (also my favorite one), based on the facts:
 (1)Generalized elementary transformation does not change the rank of a matrix.
(2).$$r\begin{pmatrix}
      A     &   C \\
      0     &   B
 \end{pmatrix}\ge r(A)+r(B)$$