# $\matrix {AB}=\matrix 0$ and $\matrix A\not= \matrix 0$, then $|\matrix B|=0$ ?!

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples

Let $A$ and $B$ be two square matrices such that $\matrix {AB}=\matrix 0$, where $\matrix 0$ denotes the Null Matrix.

My textbook mentions that [without proof]: if $\matrix A\not= \matrix 0$, then $|\matrix B|=0$.

I am not sure if this is even correct:

Consider the scenario: $|\matrix B|=k$, where $k$ is a non-zero constant and $|\matrix A|=0$ with $\matrix A\not =\matrix 0$, then this above property predicts that the product $\matrix {AB}$ cannot be $\matrix 0$. Though I could not find counter-examples, this seems improbable.

- Is this property true?
- If not, can you provide counter-example of the kind I mentioned?

Comment: If $det(B)\neq 0$, then $B$ is invertible. $AB=0$ implies that $A=0$. Contradiction.

Comment: If B has an inverse you could right multiply to get A=0. Thus B can't have an inverse.

Comment: In fact, for any $n$-by-$n$ matrix over a fixed field $B$, there exists an $m$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ such that $AB=0$ if and only if $\det(B)=0$.  In general, for any $n$-by-$r$ matrix $B$, there exists an $m$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ such that $AB=0$ if and only if $\text{rank}(B)<n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that saying $|B|=0$ is very different from saying $B=0$ (assuming that $|B|$ denotes the determinant of $B$).

If $\det B\ne0$, then $B$ is invertible, so from $AB=0$ you get
$$
A=ABB^{-1}=0B^{-1}=0
$$

---

On the other hand it is easy to find nonzero matrices with zero product:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
but this doesn't contradict the above: indeed both matrices have zero determinant.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $dim(ker(A)) + dim(ker(B)) \geq dim(ker(AB))$.

([Sylvester rank inequality: $\operatorname{rank} A + \operatorname{rank}B \leq \operatorname{rank} AB + n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298836/sylvester-rank-inequality-operatornamerank-a-operatornamerankb-leq-o))

As $AB=0$, hence $dim(ker(AB)) = n$ (where A and B are $n \times n$ matrices.)

Hence, $dim(ker(A)) + dim(ker(B)) \geq n$.

As $A\neq0$, $dim(ker(A))<n$.

So, $dim(ker(B))>0$.

Thus, $B$ is not invertible. Hence, $|B| = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $AB=0$ and $A\ne0$, then $aB=0$ for every nonzero row $a$ of $A$. Hence $B$ has linearly dependent rows (because $aB$ is a non-trivial linear combination of the rows of $B$) and its determinant must be zero.

Note that this proof is very basic: it works over any commutative ring (not just over fields) and the notion of determinant was devised to detect linear dependence in the first place.