# Does Sylvester Rank Inequality holds for a matrix over finite field?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, matrix-rank

Given $A$ and $B$ are matrices over finite field $\mathbb{Z}_p$ ($p$ is a prime number), does this statement holds ?
$$\operatorname{rank} A + \operatorname{rank}B \leq \operatorname{rank} AB + n.$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sylvester rank inequality: $\operatorname{rank} A + \operatorname{rank}B \leq \operatorname{rank} AB + n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298836/sylvester-rank-inequality-operatornamerank-a-operatornamerankb-leq-o) ; the proofs given there work in any field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sylvester's rank inequalities hold over any field $K$. However, they may not hold over rings in general - see for example the article [Rank inequalities over semirings](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228966163_Rank_inequalities_over_semirings) and its references.

Comment: What about Frobenius Inequality ? Does it holds for a matrix over finite field ?

Comment: This is also answered in the linked paper!

Comment: This is why you should learn linear algebra from a proper text that doesn't dumb it down to real numbers.