# Rank of composition of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, function-and-relation-composition

Consider $F: U \to V$ and $g: V \to W$ I have to show that
$$rk(g \circ F) \geq rk(F) + rk(g) - \dim(V)$$

Where as usual the rank is the dimension of the image.

**Attempts**

In general $im(g\circ F) \subseteq im(g)$ whence $rk(g) \geq rk(g\circ F)$.
Using the rank theorem:

$$\dim(V) = \dim\ker(g) + \dim(im(g))$$
hence $\dim(V) \geq rk(g)$.

If I consider $im(F) \subseteq V$ then $\dim(im(F)) \leq \dim(V)$ hence $rk(F) \leq \dim(V)$.

So far I got:

- $rk(g) \geq rk(g \circ F)$
- $\dim(V) \geq rk(g)$
- $\dim(V) \geq rk(F)$
- rk(F) \geq rk(g \circ F)$

Now I thought of looking at the kernel: $\ker(F) \subseteq \ker (g\circ F)$ hence $\dim(\ker(F)) \leq \dim \ker (g\circ F)$. Again using the rank theorem

$$\dim(U) = \dim(im(F)) + \dim\ker(F)$$

$$\dim(U) = \dim(im (g\circ F)) + \dim(\ker(g\circ F))$$

so $\dim(im(F)) + \dim(\ker(F)) = \dim(im(g\circ F)) + \dim(\ker (g\circ F))$$

And here I stopped becasue first of all I don't know whether all of this is right/useful, and I got stuck, not knowing how to go on...

Is there other some "simpler" way (that is: more rigorous or indeed simple) to face the problem?

**ADD**

I read this answer [show that $\operatorname{rank}(g\circ f) \leq \operatorname{rank}(f)+\operatorname{rank}(g)-n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878056/show-that-operatornamerankg-circ-f-leq-operatornamerankf-operatorna)

but I don't understand the following:

- why is $$\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rank}\rk(g\circ f)=\rk\Bigl(g_{\,\bigm\vert_{\,\scriptstyle\Im f}}\Bigr)$$
- why $$rk(g\circ f)= \dim(\Im f)-\dim(\ker g\cap\Im f)=rk f-\dim(\ker g\cap\Im f). $$

shouldn't the dimension of the composition be the dimension of $W$ minus the dimension of the kernel?

Answer (score 1):

> why is $$\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rank}\rk(g\circ f)=\rk\Bigl(g_{\,\bigm\vert_{\,\scriptstyle\Im f}}\Bigr)?$$

Note that the rank of a linear transformation is the dimension of its image. The image of $f$ is given by $\Im f = \{f(u): u \in U\}$. With that, we have
$$
\Im (g|_{\Im f}) = \{g(x):x \in \Im  f\} = \{g(f(u)): u \in U\}.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\Im (g \circ f) = \{(g \circ f)(u): u \in U\} = \{g(f(u)): u \in U\}.
$$
So, $\Im (g \circ f) = \Im (g|_{\Im f})$. It follows that
$$
\text{rank} (g \circ f) = \dim Im (g \circ f) = \dim \Im (g|_{\Im f}) = \text{rank}(g|_{\Im f}).
$$

> why $$\rk(g\circ f)= \dim(\Im f)-\dim(\ker g\cap\Im f)=rk f-\dim(\ker g\cap\Im f)?$$

Again, recall that $\text{rank} (g \circ f) = \text{rank}(g|_{\Im f})$. Applying the rank-nullity theorem to $g|_{\Im f} : \Im f \to W$ yields
$$
\rk(g|_{\Im f}) = \dim (\Im f)  - \dim \ker (g|_{\Im f}).
$$
We know that $\dim(\Im f) = \rk(f)$. The trick from here is to show that $\ker (g|_{\Im f}) = \ker g \cap \Im f$. That just comes from the definition of the kernel and the definition of the restriction $g|_{\Im f}$. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\ker g|_{\Im f} &= \{v \in \Im f : g(v) = 0\} 
\\ & = \{v \in V: v \in \Im f \text{ and } g(v) = 0\} 
\\ & = \{v \in V: v \in \Im f \} \cap \{v \in V: g(v) = 0\} = \Im f \cap \ker g.
\end{align*}
$$

---

Here's an alternative approach you might find helpful. We can rewrite the inequality as
$$
\dim(U) - \rk(g \circ F) \leq \dim(U) - [\rk(F) + \rk(g) - \dim(V)] \iff\\
\dim(U) - \rk(g \circ F) \leq (\dim U - \rk F) + (\dim V - \rk g) \iff\\
\dim \ker (g \circ F) \leq  \dim \ker F + \dim \ker g.
$$
So, it suffices to show that this last inequality holds. One approach to this is to show that
$$
\ker(g \circ F) = \{u \in U: F(u) \in \ker(g)\}.
$$
From there, one could show that for any subspace $S \subset U$, we have
$$
\dim\{u \in U: u \in F(u) \in S\} \leq \dim(S) + \ker(F).
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!! That was really clear.