# For $n\times n$ matrix $A$, there exists $B$ such that $AB=BA=0$ and $rk(A) + rk(B) = n$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> For every $n\times n$ matrix $A$, there exists $B$ such that $AB=BA=0$ and
>   $rk(A) + rk(B) = n$

The question is to prove or disprove this.

I think it is true. Take a $n\times n$ matrix $\tilde A$ in Echelon form where $a_1, \cdots a_k$ are linearly independent row vectors
$$\tilde A = \begin{bmatrix}
 -- &a_1 & -- \\
 \;&\cdots\\
-- &a_k & -- \\
0& \cdots & 0 \\
0& \cdots & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
We can define 
$$\tilde B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &\cdots & 0 &|&\cdots &|\\
0 &\cdots & 0 &  |&\cdots &|\\
0 &\cdots & 0 & b_1& \cdots& b_{n-k}\\
0 &\cdots & 0 &|&\cdots &|\\
0 &\cdots & 0 &|&\cdots &|\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where column vectors $b_1,\cdots b_{n-k}$ are linearly independent vectors from 
$$\text{span}\{a_1, \cdots a_k\}^\perp.$$
Now clearly $\tilde A \tilde B = \tilde B \tilde A = 0$.

Now for general $A$, we know row operation and swapping two rows are given by invertible matrices multiplied on the left side, so there exists a invertible matrix $P$ such that 
$$A = P \tilde A$$
where $\tilde A$ is in Echelon form. Now just define 
$$B = \tilde B P^{-1}$$
we have $AB = BA = 0$ and $$rk(A)+rk(B) = rk(\tilde A)+rk(\tilde B) = n.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What is $n$ in the statement you want to prove?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco sorry $A,B$ are $n\times n$ matrices

Comment: This looks correct!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298836/sylvester-rank-inequality-operatornamerank-a-operatornamerankb-leq-o