# Question about elementary row operations with block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Given two $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, form a new block matrix

$$P := \begin{bmatrix}I_n&B\\-A&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Then by using only elementary row operations, show that $P$ can be transformed into

$$P' := \begin{bmatrix}I_n&B\\0&AB\end{bmatrix} $$

---

The solution to this problem is:

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}I_n&B\\-A&0\end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix}I_n&B\\-A + AI_n &0 + AB\end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix}I_n&B\\0&AB\end{bmatrix}$$

I don't understand this solution. Why can $A$ be multiplied from the left on the first half of the matrix and then be added to the second half of the matrix to form a sequence of elementary row operations?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're trying to prove [Sylvester rank inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298836/sylvester-rank-inequality-operatornamerank-a-operatornamerankb-leq-o/438762#438762).

This works just like the elementary row operations. We can do this with block matrices:

$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix}A+K\,C&B+K\,D\\C&D\end{pmatrix}
$$

What we are doing here behind the scenes is multiplying the matrix by an [elementary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Row-addition_transformations) $T$:

$$
T = \begin{pmatrix}I&K\\0&I\end{pmatrix} 
$$

So we get:

$$
TM =
\begin{pmatrix}I&K\\0&I\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}A+K\,C&B+K\,D\\C&D\end{pmatrix}
$$

As you can see, $T$ has full rank and therefore invertible, which means it doesn't change rank of the matrix:

$$\operatorname{rk}TM = \operatorname{rk}M$$

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}R_{1} \\  {R_{2}}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}I_n&B\\-A&0\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Then 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}R_{1} \\  {R_{2}}\end{bmatrix}  \underset{\text{RowOp}}{\mapsto} \begin{bmatrix}R_{1} \\  {R_{2} + A R_{1}}\end{bmatrix}
\implies
\begin{bmatrix}I_n&B\\-A&0\end{bmatrix} 
\underset{\text{RowOp}}{\mapsto} 
\begin{bmatrix}I_n&B\\-A+AI_{n}& 0+AB\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}I_n&B\\0& AB\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Does this make it any clear?

Comment: No. Why is $$\begin{bmatrix}R_{1} \\  {R_{2}}\end{bmatrix}  \underset{\text{RowOp}}{\mapsto} \begin{bmatrix}R_{1} \\  {R_{2} + A R_{1}}\end{bmatrix}$$ a row operation?