# How to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices then $\operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B) \le \operatorname{rank}(AB) + n$

Tags: matrix-rank

> Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices then $\operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B) \le \operatorname{rank}(AB) + n$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE Maybe can you show your attempts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sylvester rank inequality: $\operatorname{rank} A + \operatorname{rank}B \leq \operatorname{rank} AB + n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298836/sylvester-rank-inequality-operatornamerank-a-operatornamerankb-leq-o)