# Proving that $\text{rank}(\phi \circ \psi) \geq \text{rank}(\phi) + \text{rank}(\psi) - n$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $\phi$ and $\psi: V \to V$ be linear operators on a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$. Show that
> $$
> \text{rank}(\phi \circ \psi) \geq \text{rank}(\phi) + \text{rank}(\psi) - n. 
> $$

The only machinery I think I have to use for this are the rank nullity theorem and the fact that a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space is finite-dimensional with dimension less than or equal to the larger space. The rank nullity theorem implies the following:
\begin{align*}
n = \dim V = \text{rank}(\phi) + \text{ker}(\phi) \\ 
n = \dim V = \text{rank}(\psi) + \text{ker}(\psi) \\
n = \dim V = \text{rank}(\phi \circ \psi) + \text{ker}(\phi \circ \psi)
\end{align*}
Also, if $y \in \text{Image}(\phi \circ \psi)$, then $(\phi \circ \psi)(x) = \phi(\psi(x)) = y$ for some $x$, so $y \in \text{Image}(\phi)$, so $\text{rank}(\phi) \geq \text{rank}(\phi \circ \psi)$. That doesn't seem to hlep becaause the inequality sign is reversed. I can say that $\text{ker}(\psi) \leq \text{ker}(\phi \circ \psi)$. The maps have the same domain, so I think I can then say that $\text{rank}(\psi) \geq \text{rank}(\phi \circ \psi)$. So:
\begin{align*}
\text{rank}(\phi \circ \psi) & \leq \text{rank}(\psi) \\
&= n - \text{ker}(\psi). 
\end{align*}
if I write out the above statement for $\text{rank}(\phi \circ \psi)$, then
$$
n - \text{ker}(\phi \circ \psi)  = \text{rank}(\phi \circ \psi) \leq n - \text{ker}(\psi)
$$
This unfortunately doesn't seem to work.

I'd appreciate any help on how to proceed. I'll keep updating this post as I work on this problem more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sylvester rank inequality: $\operatorname{rank} A + \operatorname{rank}B \leq \operatorname{rank} AB + n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298836/sylvester-rank-inequality-operatornamerank-a-operatornamerankb-leq-o)